# Why is this Roslyn analyzer test failing?

Tags: c#, code-generation, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm trying to understand why this test fails with:

> Maak.Test.InitializeNewUnitTest.NoPropertiesInitialized_Diagnostic
>
> Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<37>. Actual:<38>. Context:
> Diagnostics of test state Expected diagnostic to end at column "38"
> was actually at column "39"
>
> Expected diagnostic:
> // /0/Test0.cs(13,9,13,38): warning MaakInitializeNew VerifyCS.Diagnostic().WithSpan(13, 9, 13, 38),
>
> Actual diagnostic:
> // /0/Test0.cs(13,9): warning MaakInitializeNew: can be fully initialized VerifyCS.Diagnostic().WithSpan(13, 9, 13, 39),

The test:

```
[TestMethod]
        public async Task NoPropertiesInitialized_Diagnostic()
        {
            await VerifyCS.VerifyCodeFixAsync(@"
using System;

public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        [|var myClass = new MyClass { }|];
    }
}
", @"
using System;

public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var myClass = new MyClass { Name = ""Stan"" };
    }
}
");
        }
```

The analyzer code:

```
public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
        {
            // See https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/analyzers/Analyzer%20Actions%20Semantics.md for more information
            context.ConfigureGeneratedCodeAnalysis(GeneratedCodeAnalysisFlags.None);
            context.EnableConcurrentExecution();
            context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeNode, SyntaxKind.LocalDeclarationStatement);
        }

        private static void AnalyzeNode(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
        {
            var localDeclaration = (LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax)context.Node;
            var typeDeclaration = localDeclaration.Declaration.Type;
            var symbolInfo = context.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(typeDeclaration);
            var typeSymbol = symbolInfo.Symbol;
            
            if(typeSymbol == null)
                return;

            // Special case: Ensure that 'var' isn't actually an alias to another type. (e.g. using var = System.String).
            var aliasInfo = context.SemanticModel.GetAliasInfo(typeDeclaration);
            if (aliasInfo != null)
                return;

            var namedSymbol = context.Compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName(typeSymbol.MetadataName);

            if (namedSymbol?.TypeKind != TypeKind.Class)
                return;

            var hasDefaultConstructor = (namedSymbol?.Constructors)?.SingleOrDefault(c => !c.Parameters.Any()) != null;
            var properties = namedSymbol?.GetMembers()
                .Where(m => m.Kind == SymbolKind.Property
                            && m.DeclaredAccessibility == Accessibility.Public
                            && !((IPropertySymbol)m).IsReadOnly
                            && !((IPropertySymbol)m).IsStatic)
                .Select(m => new
                {
                    Name = m.Name,
                    Type = ((IPropertySymbol)m).Type
                })
                .ToList();
            var hasValidProperties = properties?.Any() != false;

            if (!hasValidProperties)
                return;

            var initializerExpressions = (localDeclaration.Declaration.Variables.FirstOrDefault().Initializer.Value
                    as ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax)?.Initializer.Expressions.ToList();
            var except = properties.Select(p => p.Name)
                .Except(initializerExpressions.Select(e => (e as AssignmentExpressionSyntax)?.Left.ToString()))
                .ToList();
            
            if(except.Count == 0)
                return;

            context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, context.Node.GetLocation()));
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reporting the correct location fixed it:

`context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, localDeclaration.Declaration.GetLocation()));`